# Find a regular expression that describes those words that don't contain two consecutive a's over the alphabet {a,b}

Tags: regex, automata

I've tried to write a grammar for the language. Here is my grammar:

**S -> aS | bS | λ**

I also wanted to generate the word "bbababb" which does not have two consecutive a's.
I started with,
bS => bbS => bbaS => bbabS => bbabaS => bbababS => bbababbS => bbababbλ => bbababb.

And finally I tried the following regular expression,
(a+b*)a*(a+b*)

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Both that grammar and regular expression accept the string "aa". You want something more like `(abb*|bb*)*`.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try to write some rules that describe all strings that don't have two consecutive a's:

1. the empty string is in the language
2. if x is a string in the language ending in a, you can add b to the end to get another string in the language
3. if x is a string in the language ending in b, you can add an a or a b to it to get another string in the language

This lets us write down a grammar:

```
S -> e | aB | bS
B -> e | bS
```

That grammar should work for us. Consider your string bbababb:

```
S -> bS -> bbS -> bbaB -> bbabS 
  -> bbabaB -> bbababS -> bbababbS
  -> bbababb
```

To turn a regular grammar such as this into a regular expression, we can write equations and solve for S:

```
S = e + aB + bS
B = e + bS
```

Replace for B:

```
S = e + a(e + bS) + bS
  = e + a + abS + bS
  = e + a + (ab + b)S
```

Now we can eliminate recursion to solve for S:

```
S = (ab + b)*(e + a)
```

This gives us a regular expression: (ab + b)*(e + a)

Comment: `(ab + b)*(e + a)` as a regular expression does not do what you think it does. For example, it would match this string `"ab        bab  bab        bab    be        a"`

Answer (score -1):

`a` must always be followed by `b`, except the last char, so you can express it as "`b` *or* `ab`, with an optional trailing `a`":

```
\b(b|ab)+a?\b
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/ZmBPbXCOnl1XQ4).

`\b` (word boundaries) might be able to be removed depending on your usage and regex engine.